# Can't query SQL Server from django using django-pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-pyodbc

I'm trying to sync an SQL Server 2008 R2 database running remotely on IIS 7, to a django 1.6 app running python 3.3 on Windows 7, using `manage.py syncdb`. However I am being met with the error,

```
TypeError: The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.
```

I have django-pyodbc 0.2.3 and pyodbc 3.0.7 installed, with my settings.py `DATABASES` as,

```
{
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django_pyodbc',
    'HOST': '...',
    'NAME': '...',
    'OPTIONS': {
      'host_is_server': True
    }
  }
}
```

As you may guess, `USER` and `PASSWORD` are omitted since I need `Integrated_Security=Yes` and `Trusted_Connection=Yes` for the connection. `OPTIONS` appears to have to be non-empty due to the way django-pyodbc initialises the class `DatabaseWrapper`, even though `host_is_server` is irrelevant on Windows.

The full error I'm receiving is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\python\ns_reports_server\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django-1.6.1-py3.3.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django-1.6.1-py3.3.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django-1.6.1-py3.3.egg\django\core\management\base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django-1.6.1-py3.3.egg\django\core\management\base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django-1.6.1-py3.3.egg\django\core\management\base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django-1.6.1-py3.3.egg\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django-1.6.1-py3.3.egg\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 157, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django_pyodbc-0.2.3-py3.3.egg\django_pyodbc\base.py", line 290, in _cursor
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django_pyodbc-0.2.3-py3.3.egg\django_pyodbc\operations.py", line 31, in _get_sql_server_ver
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django-1.6.1-py3.3.egg\django\db\backends\util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django-1.6.1-py3.3.egg\django\db\backends\util.py", line 51, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django_pyodbc-0.2.3-py3.3.egg\django_pyodbc\base.py", line 410, in execute
TypeError: The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.
```

If you look at the source code for the tenth call from the top, [django_pyodbc/operations.py](https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/blob/5cc782054f4305f10d45fca25d89f189117fdc98/django_pyodbc/operations.py#L31) is querying the connection for the SQL Server version,

```
cur.execute("SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') as varchar)")
```

Yet, by the end of the call stack, this sql to be executed has disappeared. [django_pyodbc/base.py](https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/blob/5cc782054f4305f10d45fca25d89f189117fdc98/django_pyodbc/base.py#L410) has,

```
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

for which the first argument is not being recognised as a 'string or unicode query'.

Python, django, and SQL Server are all new for me so the answer might be obvious, but I can't for the life of me work it out. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: driver_supports_utf8=True as mention in other answers would be the correct fix.

It looks like this is problem with django-pyodbc and Python 3.

In base.py, line 367 is

```
sql = sql.encode('utf-8')
```

This line turns a string into bytes which is what is causing the TypeError. As you are
on Windows, I am assuming the driver can handle unicode. I suggest you comment out lines 364 to 367 (the first 4 in the format_sql function). This way your unicode strings will stay unicode and you won't get the TypeError.

https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/blob/master/django_pyodbc/base.py

```
def format_sql(self, sql, n_params=None):
    if not self.driver_supports_utf8 and isinstance(sql, text_type):
        # Older FreeTDS (and other ODBC drivers?) don't support Unicode yet, so
        # we need to encode the SQL clause itself in utf-8
        sql = sql.encode('utf-8')
    # pyodbc uses '?' instead of '%s' as parameter placeholder.
    if n_params is not None:
        try:
            sql = sql % tuple('?' * n_params)
        except:
            #Todo checkout whats happening here
            pass
    else:
        if '%s' in sql:
            sql = sql.replace('%s', '?')
    return sql
```

I have raised an issue with django-pyodbc which goes into a little more detail.

https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/issues/47

Answer (score 2):

You can also fix this in your configuration options. I fought with this for a while. Try changing your DB to be config'd like this for 1.6:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'your_password',            
        'HOST': 'database.domain.com,1433',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'host_is_server': True,
            'autocommit': True,
            'unicode_results': True,
            'extra_params': 'tds_version=8.0'
        },
    }
}
```

If you're on Windows, the "extra_params" gets ignored, but it makes it portable to Linux.

Comment: The key part is the 'autocommit': True, for this problem (starting with Django 1.6), but if you're using Python 3.x, the unicode_results line is necessary too. Also, I've learned a bunch since this answer - while 8.0 was widely reported as correct at the time (and still works), the tds_version should actually be 7.2 under FreeTDS.

Answer (score 0):

This issue solved for us by adding `'driver_supports_utf8': True,'`

```
'characteristics': {
    'ENGINE': "django_pyodbc",
    'HOST': "ourdbhost.com",
    'PORT': 5555,
    'NAME': "OurDB",
    'USER': "ouruser",
    'PASSWORD': "acoolpw",
    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver_supports_utf8': True,
        'host_is_server': True,
        'extra_params': 'TDS_Version=7.1',
    },
},
```

worked as suggested by gri on https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/issues/47

adding

```
        'autocommit': True,
        'unicode_results': True,
```

to `OPTIONS` did not fix it, but did not break anything either